# count how many times function was executed

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I've website with image on background and i'm willing to make it move from right to left
and i do not want to use jQuery so here is my code which makes it do that movement

**HTML Code**

```
<div id="clouds_image"></div>
```

**Javascript Code**

```
var g = 0;
var speed=80;
var counter = 5;
function rollClouds() 
{
    document.getElementById('clouds_image').style.backgroundPosition=g+'px 0';
    g--;
    if (counter < 1) 
        clearInterval(interval);
}

interval = setInterval( function(){ rollClouds() }, speed)
```

**This supposed to** make the image moves from right to left and repeat its movement 5 times and counting down from 5 to 0 then will `counter < 1` so it will execute `clearInterval(interval)` to stop it.

**but** i do not know why it keep repeating without stop ! so the code might have error so any idea how to make it stop after 5 times of repeating its movement. ~ Thanks

Comment: @charlietfl It’s used for calculating position: `…=g+'px 0';`

Comment: g for position and speed for speed of move and counter maximum number of repeation should be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't seem to be decrementing the counter as your code implies you mean to do:

```
counter--;
```

Here's the full function:

```
function rollClouds() 
{
    // decrement (decrease) the counter otherwise it's never less than 1

    document.getElementById('clouds_image').style.backgroundPosition=g+'px 0';
    g--;
    if (counter < 1) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
    counter--;
}
```

Comment: @asifsid88: yes, it could be, but it seems to solve the main problem in his question so I put it here.

Comment: sorry, i didn't understood !! could you kindly rewrite the code ~ thanks

Comment: counter is maximum number of repeation should be, then may idea was to compare it with how many function rollClouds() executed but i'm newbie in javascript so do not know how to make or if there was method else.